# How to send an array of JSON objects to SAP HANA Database via HTTP POST?

Tags: json, database, sapui5, hana

I need to insert data into a SAP HANA database table via HTTP POST method. For example, I want to insert the following JSON object:

```
{"Id": "000034330", "Name":"Albert", "Type":"Customer"}
```

If I send just this object in the body of the HTTP POST request, it works fine. Although, instead of sending just one object at a time, I want to send an array of them. I tried the following format but it won't work:

```
{"entry": 
   [
      {"Id": "000034330", "Name":"Albert", "Type":"Customer"},
      {"Id": "000034331", "Name":"John", "Type":"Customer"}
   ]
}
```

Sending this format I get the following message as response:

```
The serialized resource has an missing value for member &#x0027;Id&#x0027;
```

How should I format the JSON objects array?

Comment: Not sure how you are sending data to your backend, but this sounds like a batch operation in ODataModel. Json model does not provide this mode I think. Is your service expecting data in particular format ? How would your service know to handle an object or an array ?

Comment: You could use a batch operation for multiple create requests if you are using XSODATA or you could use XSJS to send a JSON array.

Comment: @RahulBhardwaj, so I can't do a batch operation using a JSON model? Would formatting it in XML work?

Comment: Hi you can make use of xsjs and pass parameters to it using jQuery.get().
For eg: if your xsjs is called myXSJS.xsjs then you call jQuery.get() as:

`jQuery.get("Repository package/myXSJS.xsjs", {
 name: "abcd",
password: "admin"
}).done(){
  //do things if the request is succesful
}.fail(){
 //do things if request fails.
}`

But you need to save the passed parameters in the xsjs in some variable. So in your case you can make use of objects instead of what I used.

Link for reference: https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/

Answer (score 0):

You can use ajax call to update your hana database table.. following is the syntax for the ajax call

$.ajax({
'url':url,
'data':JSON.stringify(urObj),
'type':'POST', 
'success': function (data){} 
})
But you have to update your xsjs too as the data is included in header ...